Range check Error using string arrays and for loop
I am getting an error trying to run this code using C++  builder.
The code is supposed to convert a given number to the respective number systems, however, i keep getting the error: Range check error;
I dont understand because the code was running just fine in the console until I decided to put it in C++ builder to build a GUI.
I tried to debug by checking whether its the fact that no Input was coming from the frontend, but that was not the problem, then i tried to add more condition in the for loops, tried using AI to see where the problem was to no avail i still keep getting the same error, somebody help!
Here is the funciton:
String convertNumber(String number, int fromBase, int toBase) {

    // Check if the bases are valid (between 2 and 36)
    if (fromBase < 2 || fromBase > 36 || toBase < 2 || toBase > 36) {
        return "Invalid base";
    }

    // Step 1: Convert the input number (in 'fromBase') to a decimal (base 10) number
    int64_t decimalValue = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number.Length(); i++) {  // 1-based indexing
        int digitValue;
        Char currentChar = number[i - 1];  // 0-based access for characters

        // Check if the character is a digit or letter and get the digit's value
        if (isdigit(currentChar)) {
            digitValue = currentChar - '0';  // Convert character '0'-'9' to digit 0-9
        } else if (isalpha(currentChar)) {
            digitValue = toupper(currentChar) - 'A' + 10;  // Convert 'A'-'Z' to 10-35
        } else {
            return "Invalid character in input";  // Handle invalid characters
        }

        // Check if digit value is valid for the base
        if (digitValue >= fromBase) {
            return "Invalid digit for the given base";
        }

        // Convert to decimal value (manual calculation of power of the base)
        decimalValue = decimalValue * fromBase + digitValue;
    }

    // Step 2: Convert the decimal value to the target 'toBase'
    String result = "";
    if (decimalValue == 0) {
        return "0";  // Edge case: if the number is zero, return "0"
    }

    while (decimalValue > 0) {
        int remainder = decimalValue % toBase;

        // Convert the remainder to the corresponding character
        if (remainder < 10) {
            result = String((char)(remainder + '0')) + result;  // For digits 0-9
        } else {
            result = String((char)(remainder - 10 + 'A')) + result;  // For letters A-Z
        }

        decimalValue /= toBase;
    }

    return result;
}


Please post a [mre] (e.g. what is String?), and post the error that you get verbatim.

What is String? Did you implement that class, are you using a library, etc?

There is a tag [tag:c++builder] so String must be this: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.String

On topic: Why are you doing conversion from string to string to change base? You should split this into two steps: String to int64_t  then int64_t to String. Amway I'm pretty sure this is already done by VCL library, just find it in documentation and you will resolve this in just two lines. Do not reinvent the wheel.

See the following quote from the documentation 'String indexes are 1-based in desktop platforms and 0-based in mobile platforms. For more information, see Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop.' My guess then is that you have a one-based indexing system and therefore you should change Char currentChar = number[i - 1]; to Char currentChar = number[i]; Just a guess but it would explain why you get a range error.

Don't use String, use std::string. for (int i = 1; i <= number.Length(); i++) {.... C++ arrays start at index 0. Also use ranged base for loops whenever you can. But most of all use std::stoi which can do ALL of this for you.... Or aren't you writing C++ code at all?

@john Thanks, that worked! The problem as it turns out was in the fact that since the array is 1-based, subtracting 1 from it in currentChar variable brought the error range issue.

@john your comment should be an answer.

Marek is correct. C++Builder's RTL has StrToInt() and IntToHex() functions (and equivalent methods in the String class) which handle conversions for base 10 and base 16, at least.

@john "'String indexes are 1-based in desktop platforms and 0-based in mobile platforms'" - that is no longer true since 10.4 was released in 2020. String is 1-based by default on all platforms.

Thank you all for helping me figure this out, i have learnt a lot in asking this question than i could have anywhere else.

As mentioned in the comments, C++Builder's System::String type is 1-indexed, but your code is accessing its characters as-if it were 0-indexed instead.
Since your loop is using a 1-based index counter, simply change this line:
Char currentChar = number[i - 1];
To this instead:
Char currentChar = number[i];
Alternatively, as System::String implements begin/end iterators, you can use a range-for loop if you are using one of C++Builder's clang-based compilers:
for (Char currentChar : number) {
    ...
}

